# Why are Firebase documents with string fields being skipped?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have built 2 apps, one on Android and another currently in Swift (both have the same business functionality). I am fairly new to the latter. They are both fed by a Firestore collection which is also created in the aforementioned apps and then displayed via a recycler view and table view respectively.

There is a really strange scenario where one of the fields in the documents (an address field which is optional on creation) can have a null value. If it is null then the entire document is read and shows up in the table view but if it is not null then the entire document is not seen in the table view. This only happens in the iOS app.

If I remove the address field from the object altogether then I see both types of documents i.e. when the field is null AND when the field contains a string value. This weird scenario does not happen in the Android app.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my object:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Mealplan {
    var planType: Int
    var address: String

var Dictionary:[String : Any] {
    return [
        "planType": planType,
        "address": address
        ]
}

extension Mealplan : DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {

        let address = dictionary["address"] as? String,
        let planType = dictionary["planType"] as? Int

else { return nil }

        self.init(planType: planType, address: address)
}
}
```

Here is my query function in the view controller:

```
    func loadPlans() {

        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

        let userPlans = db.collection("Plans").whereField("userId", isEqualTo: user!)

        userPlans.getDocuments() { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {

                self.planArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({PlanOject(dictionary: $0.data())})
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.planTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can understand that because I set the address field as a String it would not pick up the documents that have it set as null but instead it i doing the opposite.

**Edit** 
with DB structure; first image the address field is saved as a string. In the second, the address is saved as null.

[image]
[image]

Comment: post an example of the db structure

Comment: added the DB structure with the address as a null as well as containing a string. The planType field is number.